# How to determine if an SMS Message has Images Using Twilio Studio?

Tags: image, twilio, twilio-studio

**How do I check if an SMS message has an image or not?** I'm using Twilio Studio.

- I think I should use the `Split Based On` Flow Control action...

[image]

- ...to test the `trigger.message.Body` variable.

[image]

- But what do I enter for the `Transitions` values?
- And what should I use for the `Contains` (or `Does not contain`) clause?

[image]

**Is there a way to check for BOTH a .jpg (+ .jpeg) and a .png?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of checking the `trigger.message.Body` which contains the text of the message, you should check `trigger.message.NumMedia` which tells you how many images were sent.

You can then add transitions to test whether `NumMedia` is "0" or if matches any of "1" through "10".